# Using a timer - the right way

Tags: android, performance

I'm developing an Android application and I need a timer. I need the timer to count down from, say, 15mins to 0mins but I need it to notify me every second in order to update a `View` with the current time left.

What's the proper way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect case for a [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).